# Cambiar data-value de varios options de un select a la vez con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como dice el título, necesito agregarle a los `options` de un `select` en el atributo `data-value` un id.

```
 $('#mySelect').data("value") = idresult;
```

Tengo esto pero referencia es a mi `select` y yo quiero agregarlo a todos los `options` dentro de ese `select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te funcione deberías cambiar el selector de tu función por `#mySelect option` para seleccionar los `<option>` del `<select>` con id *mySelect*.

También estás usando la función `data()` incorrectamente. Para dar valor esta espera recibir dos parámetros:

```
.data( key, value )
```

Donde **key** es el nombre de tu atributo personalizado (en tu caso "value") y **value** es el valor que quieres darle a dicho atributo (en tu caso el contenido de la variable *idresult*);

```js
$(function () {
  let idresult = 'miID';

  $('#mySelect option').data("value", idresult); 
  
  //Para comprobar que efectivamente todos los options tienen un atributo personalizado
  // "value" con valor "miID"
  console.log('Option 1: ' + $('#mySelect option:nth-child(1)').data("value"));
  console.log('Option 2: ' + $('#mySelect option:nth-child(2)').data("value"));
  console.log('Option 3: ' + $('#mySelect option:nth-child(3)').data("value"));
  console.log('Option 4: ' + $('#mySelect option:nth-child(4)').data("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">UNO</option>
  <option value="2">DOS</option>
  <option value="3">TRES</option>
  <option value="4">CUATRO</option>
</select>
```

**Referencia:** [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)